# How to reverse a list of lists?

Tags: haskell

I have a `[[a]]` type and for example it looks like:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[]]
```

But I want to make a function in Haskell which will make it look like:

```
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

I started with this function, but it does not work for a list with lists in it:

```
myreverse ::[Integer] -> [Integer]
myreverse [] = []
myreverse (h:t)= myappend (myreverse t) [h]
```

(`myappend` is a local function I have, it appends the list)

So what do I need to change in my code, to get it to work with a list containing other lists?

Comment: You're looking for a function which takes a list, and reverses it. Have you tried querying http://haskell.org/hoogle for either `reverse` or `[a]->[a]`?

Comment: @Rizier123 I am new to Haskell so only know a little syntax in it, I wrote a function which reverse the elements of the list, but I don't want that, so to answer your question, I am still figuring it out and needed some directions.

Comment: @Nia *I wrote a function which reverse the elements of the list* <- Show us this code, maybe you are closer to the solution than you think

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks I have this code for reversing it:

myreverse ::[Integer] -> [Integer]

myreverse [] = []

myreverse (h:t)= myappend (myreverse t) [h]

myappend is a function I have which appends the list.

Comment: @Rizier123  sorry for adding the code to the comment, it looks hard to read. I hope you can read it.

Comment: @Nia Just [edit] your question and add it in there.

Comment: @Rizier123 okay i will do that, thanks

Comment: @Nia FYI: See [tour] to get a quick overview of this site and see how everything works.

Comment: There is no need to put the tags in your title: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 For this you tag your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt is already very close to the solution:

```
myreverse ::[Integer] -> [Integer]
myreverse [] = []
myreverse (h:t)= myappend (myreverse t) [h]
```

Mainly you just have to change two things. First change out `Integer` with a type variable, so you can reverse lists in lists with your function. And second you want to append a list to a list here: `myappend (myreverse t) [h]` so for this, just use `++`, and you're done!

```
myreverse :: [a] -> [a]
myreverse [] = []
myreverse (h:t)= (myreverse t) ++ [h]
```

---

Also there is already a [`reverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:reverse) function out there, if you don't want to write your own:

```
Data.List.reverse [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[]]
```

output:

```
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!!!! indeed its very helpful!!! If you don't mind, can I ask you one more question regarding this matter? I have a function and its output is like this  [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[]] but I wanted it in opposite order. Now when I am applying the reverse to that function, its giving a weird output, If you don't mind would you please look at my function? if you say yes, I will put the code in my question.

Comment: @Nia You can put the function which you try right now here in the comments just but back ticks around them, e.g. \`code\`. But if you use the code from my answer everything should work fine

Comment: thank you. my function is
`prefix:: [a] -> [[a]]
 prefix[] =[]:[]
 prefix (h:t)= (h:t) : prefix (init (h:t)) `
 
When I call it with prefix [1,2,3,4],
Right now it returns 
**  [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[]] ** but when I change the last line of the function to `reverse((h:t) : prefix (init (h:t)))` it returns **[[1,2,3],[1],[],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]]
**

Comment: @Nia Don't do that in your function. Just do it when you call the function, e.g. `reverse (prefix [1,2,3,4])`

Comment: very good idea, thank you so much for being so kind and helpful!! I can not possibly thank you enough. :))

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `reverse` function, or by doing something like this:

```
reversal :: [a] -> [a]
reversal [] = []
reversal (x : xs) = (reversal xs) ++ [x]
```

Using this on your example:

```
*Main> reversal [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[]]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```